# Change Postgres search_path with Ecto

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'd like to use a specific Postgres schema for my Phoenix app.

I tried to achieve this with `Ecto.Repo.after_connect/1` callback but it seems to recursively create new db connections about 10 times before timing out.

Here is my repo file :

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo do

  use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :my_app
  use Scrivener, page_size: 20

  def after_connect(_pid) do
    IO.puts "after_connect"
    Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(MyApp.Repo, "SET search_path TO 'my_app';", [])
  end

end
```

Comment: If you want to do that permanently, you can change the search path for the user using `alter user set ...`

Comment: I don't want to. My purpose is to share a single Heroku Postgres database between 3 different apps (each one has a schema)

Comment: Then why don't you create three different users, each one with the specific schema as their default search_path?

Comment: Because I can't. Heroku provides a single database with a single user.

Comment: I don't think your use case is a good one, but the question is still valid.

Comment: Why that? I want to share a $50 database between 3 small apps for cost optimization (it would of course had been better if I could have created 3 separated databases for the same $50)

Comment: Why don't you change your three "apps" to only use schema-qualified names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the timeout happens because after_connect is still too early in ecto's setup cycle.  Using ecto 2 (still in beta) the following works, whether it works in ecto 1 would depend on whether you get the connection as a parameter in after_connection).

In your repo:

```
defmodule Et.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :et

  def set_search_path(conn, path) do
    {:ok, _result} = Postgrex.query(conn, "SET search_path=#{path}", [])
  end
end
```

In your config.exs file:

```
config :et, Et.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  database: "......",
  username: "......",
  hostname: "localhost",
  after_connect: {Et.Repo, :set_search_path, ["app,public,extensions"]}
```

Hope that helps, --Kip

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and the first solution I have found was add the `prefix` (called schema, in postgres) in every access to my apps's Repo module.
But in the recent versions of ecto and phoenix_ecto, you can modify the postgres's schema of your model just adding the attribute `@schema_prefix "your_schema"`.

Example:

```
defmodule YourApp.YourModel do
  use YourApp.Web, :model

  @schema_prefix "your_schema"
  schema "your_model" do
    field :name, :string
  end

  # more stuff...
end
```

You can check the discussion about this feature, and another ways to solve this issue, at ecto's github: https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/issues/978

PS: This solve the database access for your model, but for other regular queries, you would specify prefix at your query:

```
%{query | prefix: "your_schema"}
```

I hope I've helped!

Comment: Thanks Fernando. It's the best answer so far, but I was looking for a less obtrusive way to switch schema. I will go with this for now.

Comment: It's the best solution I've found until now :)